# For x between 0 and 1, what does the following series converge to?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the following infinite series:

$\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} 2^i x^{(2^i)} = 2x^2 + 4x^4 + 8x^8 + 16x^{16} + ...$

I know that it converges for values of x between 0 and 1- can anyone help find a closed form in terms of x?

Comment: This is closely related to so called lacunary series. I'm afraid there isn't going to be a nice closed form.

Comment: Thanks very much! Helps quite a bit.